# MVC Repository pattern where data will be loaded from multiple table

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, repository-pattern

I am using MVC 5 with EF6 for developing an application. I am following Repository design pattern. As-usual there is a Generic Repository layer, which has a type parameter, GenericRepository<'T'>. The repository contains GetAll function:

```
    public virtual List<T> GetAll()
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
        return query.ToList();
    }
```

This repository has been called from service layer. In service layer There is also a function called GetAll(). The function is like:

```
    public List<Student> GetAll()
    {
        return _unitOfWork.StudentRepository.GetAll();
    }
```

Repository deals with single entity at a time. In this example I am retrieving data from Student table only. My problem is that if I want to retrieve data from more than one table, say Student Department and Country and display it in view, how is it possible? My controller code is like:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(student.GetAll());
        }
```

How and where should I include "Location" and "State" entities. I also has a UnitOfWork layer. The layer is like:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
    {
        private readonly ConnString _context;
        private IGenericRepository<Student> studentRepository;
        private IGenericRepository<Department> departmentRepository;
        private IGenericRepository<Country> countryRepository;

        public UnitOfWork()
        {
            this._context = new ConnString();
        }

        public IGenericRepository<Student> StudentRepository
        {
            get { return this.studentRepository ?? (this.studentRepository = new GenericRepository<Student>(_context)); }
        }
```

Another problem is that if I want to generate dropdown list in view (e.g., Department and Country), how can I do this?

Any help will be thankfully accepted.

Thanks
Partha

Comment: If I understood it correctly, ideally your service layer or your controller can orchestrate getting data from multiple repositories, club them into single entity(may be by include chaining if your repository methods return `IQueryable<T>` instead of collections or by conditionally querying each repository based on parent data) and pass it back.

Comment: In service layer I am returning "<Student>" entity as list in GetAll() function. Student is single entity. I need something like <StudentDepartmentLocationViewModel>. How is it possible by this pattern?

Comment: I believe you have just discovered why EF uses a single repository with multiple entity types: the DbContext.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all. The repository pattern doesn't wrap tables. It wraps domain entities. They might or might not be stored in a single table.

For your scenario it's the controllers job to take information from the model (business layer) and adapt it to the requirements that the view has.

Thus I would do something like this:

```
var students = _studentRepos.GetStudentsInSchool(schoolId);
var departmentIds = students.Select(x=>x.DepartmentId).Distinct();
var departments = _departmentRepos.GetAll(departmentIdS);
var countryIds = studens.Select(x=>x.CountryId).Distinct();
var countries = _countryRepos.GetAll(countryIds);

var items = new List<StudentSummaryModel>();
foreach (var student in studens)
{
    var item = new StudentSummaryModel(student);
    item.CountryName = countries.First(x=>x.Id == student.CountryId).Name;
    item.DepartmentName = departments.First(x=>x.Id == student.DepartmentId).Name;
    items.Add(item)
}

return View(items);
```

Code is reasonable easy to read and the different business domains are separated.

Comment: If data shall be added, transactions might be desired, to assure that both entries are added only if i.e. a student is only added to an existing department, or a new department is only added if it's missing and only if the student is added too. While in a simple MVC pattern the controller is responsible, transactions shouldn't be part of controllers in any case. This answer is proposing a service, where transactions could be reasonable implemented: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41297655/how-to-add-record-to-multiple-tables-in-mvc-through-ef-repositry

Comment: Another aspect is to keep the controller as slim as possible. Having there much logic makes it hard to read and is not focused on handling requests but on details that are better outsourced in specific class(es).

Comment: All points are valid, David, but you expanded the answer beyond the question.